# PHP extension function array_init throws 'return_value is undeclared'

Tags: php, c++, arrays, php-extension

For the first time I'm trying to create PHP extenstion. I need a function that will return an assoc array. So for the test reasons I created a small function:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(testing_array) {
    char *firstVal = NULL;
    char *secondVal= NULL;
    int argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
    int firstVal_len;
    int secondVal_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(argc TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &firstVal, &firstVal_len, &secondVal, &secondVal_len) == FAILURE)
        return;

    array_init(return_array);
}
```

But everytime I'm tryimg to compile it, compiler tells me:

```
/root/php/php-src/ext/hello_world/hello_world.c:87: error: return_array undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/php/php-src/ext/hello_world/hello_world.c:87: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/root/php/php-src/ext/hello_world/hello_world.c:87: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

What I'm doing wrong? In every example I saw, array variable isn't declared.

Comment: For a start you never declared return_array as the error saying, should it not be array_init(testing_array)?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of the `PHP_FUNCTION()` macro.  It declares the argument `return_value` *not* `return_array`.  That's why the latter isn't declared.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear. You have to declare the variable `return_array` before use it.

Comment: I know that I need to declare it, but in every tutorial, in every example I saw, it never declared. You can see it here https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/filter.c#L889 - this is a code of filter_list() -function from the standart php extension "filter".